# converting a dataframe to a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working with a data `Adult` that I have changed and would like to save it as a csv. however after saving it as a csv and re-loading the data to work with again, the data is not converted properly. The headers are not preserved and some columns are now combined. I have looked through the page and online, but what I have tried is not working. I load the data in with the following code:

```
import numpy as np ##Import necassary packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import *
url2="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data" #Reading in Data from a freely and easily available source on the internet
Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True) #Decoding data by removing extra spaces in cplumns with skipinitialspace=True
##Assigning reasonable column names to the dataframe
Adult.columns = ["age","workclass","fnlwgt","education","educationnum","maritalstatus","occupation",  
                 "relationship","race","sex","capitalgain","capitalloss","hoursperweek","nativecountry",
                 "less50kmoreeq50kn"]
```

After inserting missing values and changing the data frame as desired I have tried:

```
df = Adult

df.to_csv('file_name.csv',header = True)

df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

and a few other variations. How can I save the file to a CSV and preserve the correct format for the next time I read the file in?

When re-loading the data I use the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
```

when running `df.head` the output is:

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of        Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1  age  ... Black  Asian-Pac-Islander Other
0               0             0   39  ...     0                   0     0
1               1             1   50  ...     0                   0     0
2               2             2   38  ...     0                   0     0
3               3             3   53  ...     1                   0     0
```

and `print(df.loc[:,"age"].value_counts())` the output is:

```
36    898
31    888
34    886
23    877
35    876
```

which should not have 2 columns

Comment: Can you give an example of the row you are using to reload the data and an example of the bad data that comes up? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DanielGeffen I have made some edits so hopefully its a little more clear

Comment: You are seeing two columns when printing `age` because the first column is the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save the dataframe in general, the first column is the index, and you sould load the index when reading the dataframe, also whenever you assign a dataframe to a variable make sure to copy the dataframe:

```
df = Adult.copy()
df.to_csv('file_name.csv',header = True)
```

And to read:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', index_col=0)
```

The first columns from `print(df.loc[:,"age"].value_counts())` is the index column which is shown if you query the datframe, to save this to a list, use the `to_list`method:

```
print(df.loc[:,"age"].value_counts().to_list())
```

Comment: Thank you This helped me figure out where I was gong wrong

Answer (score 2):

If you [pickle it](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) like so:

```
Adult.to_pickle('adult.pickle')
```

You will, subsequently, be able to read it back in using [read_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html#pandas.read_pickle) as follows:

```
original_adult = pd.read_pickle('adult.pickle')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice solutions, but be careful, never unpickle from an untrusted source. The pickle module of python is not secure. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Thank you, I have did not know about pickle, it was the best path for me, but I will definitely keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: Care to change the accepted answer then if it was "the best path"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the output column order you can specify the columns directly while saving the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

url2 = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data" 
df = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True)

my_columns = ["age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "educationnum", "maritalstatus", "occupation",
             "relationship","race","sex","capitalgain","capitalloss","hoursperweek","nativecountry",
             "less50kmoreeq50kn"]
df.columns = my_columns

# do the computation ...

df[my_columns].to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

You can add parameter `index=False` to the `to_csv('file_name.csv', index=False)` function if you are not interested in saving the DataFrame row index. Otherwise, while reading the csv file again you'd need to specify the `index_col` parameter.

---

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)  `value_counts()` returns a `Series` object - you see two columns because the first one is the index - Age (36, 31, ...), and the second is the count (898, 888, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your code and it works for me. The order of the columns is preserved.

Let me show what I tried. Tried this batch of code:

```
import numpy as np ##Import necassary packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import *

url2="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/adult/adult.data" #Reading in Data from a freely and easily 
available source on the internet

Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True) #Decoding data 
by removing extra spaces in cplumns with skipinitialspace=True

##Assigning reasonable column names to the dataframe
Adult.columns =["age","workclass","fnlwgt","education","educationnum","maritalstatus","occupation",  
             "relationship","race","sex","capitalgain","capitalloss","hoursperweek","nativecountry",
             "less50kmoreeq50kn"]
```

This worked perfectly. Then

```
df = Adult
```

This also worked.
Then I saved this data frame to a csv file. Make sure you are providing the absolute path to the file even if is is being saved in the same folder as this script.

```
df.to_csv('full_path_to_the_file.csv',header = True)
# so someting like
#df.to_csv('Users/user_name/Desktop/folder/NameFile.csv',header = True)
```

Load this csv file into a new_df. It will generate a new column for keeping track of index. It is unnecessary and you can drop it like following:

```
new_df = pd.read_csv('Users/user_name/Desktop/folder/NameFile.csv', index_col = None)
new_df= new_df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis =1)
```

When I compare the columns of the new_df from the original df, with this line of code

```
new_df.columns == df.columns
```

I get

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

You might not have been providing the absolute path to the file or saving the file twice as here. You only need to save it once.

```
df.to_csv('file_name.csv',header = True)

df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```